# prevent bad bots that don't check robots.txt from launching app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, bots

my Google App Engine site is being crawled by a lot of bots and it got much worse recently. The number of bots skyrocketed and most of them don't check robots.txt and it costs me.  Is there a way to prevent bad bots that don't check robots.txt from launching app engine?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not, `robots.txt` is only effective for the well-behaved bots which properly implement and respect the conventions. From [How do I prevent robots scanning my site?](http://www.robotstxt.org/faq/prevent.html):

> The quick way to prevent robots visiting your site is put these two
>   lines into the /robots.txt file on your server:
>
> ```
> User-agent: *
> Disallow: /
> ```
>
> but this only helps with well-behaved robots.
>
> See [Can I block just bad robots?](http://www.robotstxt.org/faq/blockjustbad.html)

And from the quoted link:

> **Can I block just bad robots?**
>
> In theory yes, in practice, no. If the bad robot obeys /robots.txt,
>   and you know the name it scans for in the User-Agent field. then you
>   can create a section in your /robotst.txt to exclude it specifically.
>   But almost all bad robots ignore /robots.txt, making that pointless.
>
> If the bad robot operates from a single IP address, you can block its
>   access to your web server through server configuration or with a
>   network firewall.
>
> If copies of the robot operate at lots of different IP addresses, such
>   as hijacked PCs that are part of a large [Botnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botnet), then it becomes
>   more difficult. The best option then is to use advanced firewall rules
>   configuration that automatically block access to IP addresses that
>   make many connections; but that can hit good robots as well your bad
>   robots.

Comment: I don't mind blocking good and bad robots but how I can block access to IP addresses that make many connections? The problem that bots that come to my site change IP addresses or those just different bots.

Comment: AFAIK GAE firewall doesn't offer support for automatically detecting and blocking abusive IPs. Doing it manually or even automating it yourself (using [the ADMIN API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.firewall.ingressRules)) isn't IMHO really practical (except maybe for a few particular cases).